# Embed SharePoint PowerShell with a C# Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am running a C# web application in 3.5 framework with Any CPU as target.
My Machine Config:
Windows 7 with 64bit OS
Visual Studio 2010
SharePoint 2010

I am trying to call a SharePoint PowerShell script from my web application. But failed. Below is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;


namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            string scriptText = ReadPowerShellScript("D:\\SiteHierarchy_project\\scriptSC.ps1");
            RunspaceConfiguration rsConfig = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            PSSnapInException snapInException = null;
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();

            PSSnapInInfo info = rsConfig.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell", out snapInException);
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
            string scriptSnapIn = "Get-PsSnapin -Registered";
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptSnapIn);

            Runspace RunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rsConfig);
            RunSpace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeLine = RunSpace.CreatePipeline();
            Command scriptCommand = new Command(scriptText);
            pipeLine.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

            // execute the script        
            //  Collection<PSObject> commandResults = pipeLine.Invoke();
            pipeLine.Invoke();
            // close the runspace        
            RunSpace.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }

    }

    public string ReadPowerShellScript(string Script)
    {
        //Read script         
        //StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath(Script));
        StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(Script);
        string strContent = objReader.ReadToEnd();
        objReader.Close();
        return strContent;
    } 
}
```

}

and getting the below error.

"The Windows PowerShell snap-in 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell' is not installed on this machine."

Please let me know , where i am doing wrong

Thanks ,
Sandeep

Comment: Why would you want to invoke a powershell script, you are all ready in managed code with the relevant permissions to access the SharePoint OM directly?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have sharepoint installed on the web server in which you are running this code? The error message is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yes, i have SharePoint 2010 installed on the machine on which i running this web application. Both SharePoint 2010 and VS 2010 are installed on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea;
Create batch file to call .ps1 file. And instead of calling .ps1 file directly from code, you can call batch file using System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ;

Comment: Thanks Rahil for the idea, i had done the same way as you had said. But the problem is somewhere else. VS 2010 works on 32 bit and SharePoint Powershell works on 64 bit. So whenever i was trying to call the powershell from within my web application, it is pointing to 32 bit powershell and which is wrong. So i give the path of 64 bit powershell and it works. Below is the working code

Comment: please post your code for other visitors. Also mark answer and vote. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is call the 64 bit powershell than only it works from the VS 2010.

I had called the Powershell script from the batch file and my batch file is calling the 64 bit poweshell.

In my batch file i wrote
%windir%\sysnative\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell -File "C:\filepath\Poweshellfile.ps1" auto

Now application is working fine.

Sandeep Tiwari
MCTS SharePoint 2010